# WordPress Permalink <?php the_permalink(); ?>

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to grab a permalink for a page in WordPress and am using the following:

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

It works fine, but I need to strip something out of the output.  It returns the following:

```
http://www.testing.com/es/patients/
```

Which is correct, but I want to strip out the "/es"

Is there a command I can add to this to strip out the /es and have it just say:

```
http://www.testing.com/patients/
```

Comment: it's just a string, so you can mangle it however you want. quick/dirty: `str_replace('/es', '', get_the_permalink())`

Comment: Would it look like this? <?php str_replace('/es', '', the_permalink()) ?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to include those PHP lines on your page:

```
<?php
   $url = the_permalink();
   $final_url = str_replace("/es", "", $url);
   echo $final_url;
?>
```

Then you can work in that edited variable $final_url

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with your code Marcin.  Seems to be giving the same URL still with the /es

Comment: are you adding code in the right place? echo each variable and see the outputs

Comment: It actually works perfect.  I needed to change the_permalink to get_permalink - so if you want to edit that.  Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Do you not need to escape the slash? i.e. `$final_url = str_replace("\/es", "", $url);`

Comment: I'd also change it to replace "/es/" with "/" -- that way, in case the permalink slug begins with 'es', then it won't be erroneously replaced as well